# Compare floating numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I want to compare two floating numbers to see if $a is greater than $b.
So if:

$a = 1.23.94

$b = 1.23.90

If a is greater than b i want to echo "whatever".

Also need to allow for possibility of a number being 1.23.100 and comparing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to simply compare the two variables

```
if($a > $b) {
 echo "whatever";
}
```

this link also may help you.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

notice that php has its floating point precision